# Can I edit IE Favorites from the command line?

Tags: windows-7, internet-explorer, bookmarks

I have several dozen Favorites in Internet Explorer that have the same root URL. That URL has now changed and I need to update all the Favorites. I want to write a script to go in and replace the old root with the new one, but I don't know how to edit the properties of an IE Favorite. Just converting them to a text file that I could edit and then re-import would be a fine option too. Can anyone tell me how to do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Internet Explorer Favorites (`.URL` files) are plain-text in nature, so just open them as if they are a text file and edit them (either manually or via a script).

Example Favorite contents:

```
[{000214A0-0000-0000-C000-000000000046}]
Prop3=19,2
[InternetShortcut]
URL=http://superuser.com/questions/832846/can-i-edit-ie-favorites-from-the-command-line
IDList=
IconFile=http://cdn.sstatic.net/superuser/img/favicon.ico?v=c82914fca0a9
IconIndex=1
```

Comment: perfect! Just what I needed. I ended up just opening the Favorites folder (`C:\Users\[username]\Favorites`), selecting all the shortcuts I wanted to change, dragging them all into Notepad++, doing a single `Replace in All Open Documents`, `Save All`. Done! Took less time than writing this comment. Thanks for the assist!

Comment: That's exactly what I would have suggested/done. Notepad++ rules. :)